# Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")

Tags: bash

i'm writing a script but get the error : Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")
I don't really see where the error could be

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in "$@"

do

mv "$dir"/* /tmp

done

if [ $# -lt 1 ] ; then

echo "ERROR: no argument"

exit 1  # pas 0

else

   case $#

   -d) mv -R $dir/* /tmp        
       ;;

-x) find -executable -type f | xargs mv -t "$dir"/* /tmp

;;

esac

fi
```

Comment: Is your script really double-spaced like that? All those blank lines aren't particularly helpful. Consistent indentation would be.

Comment: You might want to read about the `getopts` command in the `bash` man page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error says, "in" is missing. Per [the case syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs),

> case word *in* [ [(] pattern [| pattern]…) command-list ;;]… esac

but there is no "in" after the word (`$#`) in the code - add it.

Comment: Not to mention that `$#` is never going to match either `-d` or `-x`.

Comment: And the syntax checking and what not should probably be done first, before the destructive `mv` commands start rearranging things...